# SharePoint Top Navigation Bar - Mega Menu Sublink Strings Overflowing - Overflow Ellipsis No Longer Triggering

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, navigation, top-navigation, megamenu

The mega menu in the top navigation bar for the site I am working on is no longer triggering the overflow ellipsis function for sublink strings that are too long. Instead, the strings are just spilling over into the next header link section within the menu.

This happened a few days ago out of the blue. I can recall no specific action that caused it. Does anybody else have a similar issue or a recommended fix?

**Example of the Issue**:

[image]

Comment: Did you add any custom CSS/JS using SPFx on this SharePoint site / page recently which might break the functionality?

Comment: Is this happening from all SharePoint pages or single page?

Answer (score 0):

I just test this in our SharePoint site and it is working fine for us. If the navigation menu display name is long, it is showing the ellipsis as shown below:

[image]

If you have not deployed any custom solution using SPFx on this site which might break the existing functionality, I will suggest you to open service request with Microsoft support directly.

Follow this documentation for same: [Get support for Microsoft 365 - Online support](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide#online-support)

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the feedback. I've tried running tests to see if it's fixed, but no luck. The overflow ellipsis is still failing to activate. 

I will consider opening a support ticket with MS directly.

Comment: Sure, please raise the ticket with Microsoft.

Comment: Please  [accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.